# How can I figure out what versions I've updated and when from SVN?

Tags: svn

Is there any way to know what specific revisions I've updated my application to and when? Ideally what I want is a checkout log, that indicates "On DAY this path went to rev XYZ"

Is this even possible/available with SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're looking in the right place, although your implementation isn't clear.

I usually have an in program bit of code that parses an expanded tag inside the checkout so that the application itself knows what revision it is running.

OIf you are talking about branching and 'paths' refer to different parts of your SVN tree, you can use `svn blame` to figure out what code came from where.

However it sounds like you are using some kind of manual checkout system and want some central unit to know who's checked out and updated to what revision. To my knowledge this is not possible internal to SVN, but you might be able to rig up something by either parsing log files (messy) or hooks.

Some clients (such as tortisesvn on windows) have built in ways of hadling a post-update hook. To do this on the *nix side you probably want to write yourself a couple line "deploy" shells script that handles the update and then logs somewhere about what client got updated to what.

If you go the log file right, you could create a checkout user for each deployment to make it easier to keep track of who's sucked what files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in short I'm not looking for a central repository solution. This is more of a client-side issue I have, Imagine I checkout (ro) the trunk from a project on sourceforge today (rev 100 comes down), tomorrow I update it (and rev 150 comes down), and again next week (and rev 200 comes down), this is the info I'm looking for, I just want to know what rev I was running at what point in time.

Comment: There is no built in mechanism for tracking this. You will need to log the information yourself. I suggest writting a wrapper script to deply your app and save the date and version somewhere, either to a separate text file or even to a custom svnprop.

Comment: mmm... that's what I feared.... Well Thanks anyway for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a web based svn viewer it should be able to give you a basic coverage of this

however from the command line:

`svn log`

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in short I'm not looking for a central repository solution. This is more of a client-side issue I have, Imagine I checkout (ro) the trunk from a project on sourceforge today (rev 100 comes down), tomorrow I update it (and rev 150 comes down), and again next week (and rev 200 comes down), this is the info I'm looking for, I just want to know what rev I was running at what point in time.

Comment: @antyhonysomerset ... this guy isn't looking for the log of what changed in SVN he's looking for a log of what revisions he's used when on the client side.